# Поддерживает ли MariaDb массивы в качестве родительского элемента в JSON полях?

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

Собственно , не могу сделать запрос вида

```
JSON_SET(json_field,"$ [ * ].key",value)
```

Только

```
JSON_SET(json_field,"$.key [ * ] .key1",value).
```

Кроме того, может ли MariaDB осуществлять запросы вида

```
UPDATE Student 
SET $.isHandicapped= CASE          
                     WHEN JSON_EXTRACT(data, "'$."data"."schoolData"."studentListe"[*]."isHandicapped")='false' 
                     THEN 'NO' 
                     ELSE 'Ja'  end
```

Как вот здесь описано:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42264346/how-to-conditional-update-field-in-json-in-mysql/55735912#55735912

Переменную вида `$.key` MariaDb отказывается распознавать.

MariaDb v10.3

Comment: По приведенной ссылке в первом ответе правильный вариант `set data=json_set(data, '$.isHandicapped')`. А второй ответ не имеет ничего общего с реальностью

Comment: Отвечая на заголовок: да, поддерживает, но только при указании конкретного элемента массива. `*` использовать нельзя. Потому как заменить можно только один элемент, а не несколько сразу